# Why this line make my program segfault?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I cut useless part of my code to make my post clearer.

Here is the problem, the first and only line in the function `init_dda()` make my programme segfault, I really don't understand how is it possible, if you have an explanation, thanks to you.

```
void    dda_algorithm(t_env *e)
{
    t_dda   *d;

    d = NULL;
    init_dda(e, d);
}

void    init_dda(t_env *e, t_dda *d)
{
    d->map_x = 3;
}
```

Here is the construction of my structure `t_dda`:

```
typedef struct  s_dda
{
    int         map_x;
}               t_dda;
```

I have no compilation error with warning flags enabled.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? where is the structured `malloc`ed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `init_dda()` call, you're passing the second argument `d` as NULL.

Then, inside `init_dda()`, you're trying to de-reference that pointer. This (dereferencing NULL pointer, which is also an invalid pointer) invokes  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Segmentation fault is one of the side effects.

**Solution:** You need to allocate memory to `d` before passing that to `init_dda()`. You can look into [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family of functions.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a value to something not initialized.

Your d pointer is null and yet your are trying to write something into it.

Answer (score 1):

You called `init_dda` with the second argument `d`, which you just assigned to `NULL`.  Hence, your code is trying to dereference NULL, which is a pretty good way to seg fault.

Answer (score 1):

`init_dda(e, d)` is called with `d=NULL`, and then trying to dereference it accessing:

```
 d->map_x = 3;
```

Which is obviously creating a memory access violation resulting in segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

There is a null pointer:

```
d = NULL;
```

Which is passed to function:

```
init_dda(e, d);
```

There you are accessing the member of this structure, which is null:

```
d->map_x = 3;
```

but **d is null**
This causes segfault